# Flask auto triggering POST request

Tags: forms, flask, post

I'm trying to make a form which requires users to put in some header information, and then also input some tabular information below.

I'm using Flask to organise the form requests, but when I input text into the form header and then click the tabs, it auto triggers a POST request, which is not the desired effect. I have a separate "save and exit" button to do this, but I can't figure out why the form header information is being pushed to a POST request without clicking that button.

If you leave the form headers empty, you can click on the tabs without triggering the POST request and I've tried removing "required" from the header forms, but that doesn't work either.

Could anyone give me some pointers as to where I'm going wrong? Many thanks!

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.w3-tab {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
} 

/* Style the buttons that are used to open the tab content */
.w3-tab button {
  background-color: inherit;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* Style the tab content */
.w3-tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>  
    function openCity(evt, cityName) {
      // Declare all variables
      var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
      // Get all elements with class="w3-tabcontent" and hide them
      tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("w3-tabcontent");
      for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
      tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
      for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
      }
      // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
      document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
      evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
      }      
</script>
    
</head>

<body>

    <form method="post">
    </p><button class="button" style="float: right;" type="submit">Save and exit</button></p>

    <!-- About Section -->

    <div class="container">
        <div class="container">
            <h3><b>About</b></h3>
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" name="city-name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter description" name="city-description" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Tab section -->
    
    <div class="w3-tab">
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
    </div>
    
    <div id="London" class="w3-tabcontent">
        <p>Here is some random tab content</p>
    </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

The Flask setup of this page:

```
from flask import (Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request,
                   session, url_for)

bp.route('city-hub/new-city', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def new_city():
    """ The create city page """
    
    session.clear()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        persona_name = request.form['city-name']
        persona_description = request.form['city-description']
        data = {'city-name':city_name,
                'city-description':city_description}

    return render_template('creation_suite/mwe.html')
```

Comment: your html structure doesn't appear to be valid. You start by opening a `form` which has no closing tag and after that you close a `</p>`, is that the code you're using? For the undesired POST request add to the `openCity` method `evt.preventDefault()`, [preventDefault() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault?retiredLocale=en)

Comment: Woops, sorry! Yep I missed the `</form>` in stripping down my code to a minimum working example... rookie error, sorry. Trying the `evt.preventDefault()` method now!

Comment: you're welcome :) When you have a button in a form it will always fire the form action on click, that's why you need to use `preventDefault`

Comment: Ohh I did not know that at all.. I'm sure there's a really sensible reason for that under the hood but I'm still learning so haven't hit those specifics yet. Okay that is really useful information to know actually going forward, thanks! :)